# displaying a sentence from input boxes

Tags: loops

i am trying to use a do loop to enter a word into an input box then enter another word in the input box and keep going until a . is entered and then the sentence will display in a label. can someone help

```
       Public Class Form1
     Private Sub btnGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click
    Dim chrFlag As Char = "."
    Dim strSentence As String = ""
    Dim strWord As String = ""
    Do
        strWord = Val(InputBox("Enter 1 Word"))

        If strWord <> chrFlag Then
            strSentence = strSentence + strWord + " "
        End If
    Loop Until strWord = chrFlag

    Me.lblDisplay.Text = strSentence
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

Your actions are out of order.  You cannot put all your code within the Click action because what you are asking for requires multiple clicks.  As you have it, all your code will execute on the first click, and you will get caught in an infinite loop.

You should have a global variable for the sentence which gets modified on every click.  You don't actually need a loop for what you are asking, just if statements.  I would write the logic like so;

```
Class Form1 {
  String sentence = "";

  Sub OnButtonClick {
    sentence = sentence + word;
    if word.equals(".") then
      view.text = sentence;
      sentence = "";
    else
      sentence = sentence + " ";
    end if
  }
}
```